# SSL error with Python 2 requests after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python

I get an SSL error with Python 2's `requests` against https://www.wikidata.org.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=L1%7CL2&format=json"
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
response = requests.get(url)
```

The first request gets through alright, albeit with a warning. The second fails with the following response:

```
>>> response = requests.get(url)
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7fe4c09ccf50>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 315, in wrapper
_lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.wikidata.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=L1%7CL2&format=json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

My Python 3 works and `curl` works:

```
curl "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=L1%7CL2&format=json"
```

The report from Qualys SSL Labs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.wikidata.org looks ok for www.wikidata.org.

I thought my dependencies was updated:

```
>>> import requests, certifi, cryptography
>>> requests.__version__
'2.18.4'
>>> certifi.__version__
'2018.01.18'
>>> cryptography.__version__
'1.5.2'

$ aptitude show openssl | grep Version
Version: 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1
```

But I see that my `requests` get the version from the Ubuntu distribution `python-requests`:

```
$ aptitude show python-requests | grep Version
Version: 2.18.4-2
```

while my pip also fails as

```
$ pip2 search requests
```

comes up with a

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
```

Due to system dependencies it seems that I cannot do

```
$ sudo aptitude remove python-requests
```

Neither does the following work:

```
$ sudo pip2 uninstall pip
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade requests
$ python2
>>> requests.__version__
'2.19.1'
>>> url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=L1%7CL2&format=json"
>>> requests.get(url)
```

Comment: You could add `verify=False` to that call for requests as a workaround.

Comment: Yes, that is the what I did in the third line (from the top). But I have `requests.get` all over my code, and furthermore I do not want to do `verify=False` in the distributed code.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
$ python2
>>> url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=L1%7CL2&format=json"
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get(url)
<Response [200]>
```